# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

Anyone help me with this error.
I'm trying to create a table named `"accounts"` with 2 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
(
accountno number(10) NULL,
accountname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
);

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts ( accountno number(10) NULL, accountname varchar2(50) NOT NULL);
```